# How can I configure the JAX-RS base path in TomEE+?

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I have a WAR with some JAX-RS services, deployed into TomEE Plus. Given a service annotated with `@Path("myservice")`, TomEE+ publishes it to `localhost:8080/mywebapp/myservice`.

However, that also makes accessing a JSP at `localhost:8080/mywebapp/index.jsp` impossible - JAXRSInInterceptor complains that `No root resource matching request path  has been found, Relative Path: /index.jsp`.

So I would like to configure a path prefix `api` to all services, which changes the `myservice` URL to `localhost:8080/mywebapp/api/myservice`. Doing so would be trivial if I had configured CXF on my own (with or without Spring), because I could simply change the URL pattern of the CXF Servlet - but I am relying on the default settings where I don't configure anything besides the annotations. So how do I do that in this case?

Note that I don't want to alter the `@Path` annotations to include the prefix, because that does not fix the issue with the JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an extension of [javax.ws.rs.core.Application](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) and annotate it with [@ApplicationPath](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) where value would be `api` in your case:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // register root resource
        classes.add(MyServiceResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

This way a Servlet 3 container would find your application and map your resource to `/mywebapp/api/myservice` while making your web resources (.jsp) available at `/mywebapp`.

Comment: Okay, that works, thanks! However, I would prefer a way to do this that does not force me to implement the `getClasses()` method. When I don't have an `Application` class, my resources are detected automatically, but when I have one and don't overwrite `getClasses()`, no resources are set up :-(

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at the CXF proprietary APIs if they're handling situations like this (Jersey does, see [ResourceConfig#packages](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#packages(java.lang.String...)), so it's not uncommon).

Answer (score 1):

TomEE trunk supports these configurations: cxf.jaxrs.staticSubresourceResolution & cxf.jaxrs.static-resources-list

but the @ApplicationPath is the more relevant solution IMO

Using -Dopenejb.webservice.old-deployment=true can help too in some cases