# Changing restAPI URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I have created an application in java with the name `hello`. my `class` is below

```
@Path("/test")
class TestAPI
{
@GET
@Path("/hi")
public String sayHi()
{
   return "Hi I am Shweta";
}
```

}

I am accessing this application using

```
GET http://localhost:8080/hello/test/hi
```

Is there anyway I can remove `hello` from `URI` or I can replace the same without changing application.

If I need to access like `http://localhost:8080/test/hi` what changes I need to do? I am using `maven`.

Comment: I think you should use [@ApplicationPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745965/5909692) will help.

Comment: What does this have to do with Spring? Seems more like -say- jax-rs to me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in your server.Say if you are using tomcat to deploy your application,Then go through its configuration file and change the context path to '/'.It will work.You just need to check where context path is defined in what ever server you are using and just replace the path with '/'.